# How to change all stringa starting with + to links?

Tags: jquery

I have a comment section and every comment shall be looped through and checked if there are strings in them starting with +. Those strings shall be converted to links. Butall my attempts didn't work.

HTML:

```
//what it actually looks like
<p class="comment">A comment with +anything</p>
<p class="comment">A comment with +anything</p>
...
//what it actually looks like
<p class="comment">A comment with <a href="anything.html">+anything</a></p>
<p class="comment">A comment with <a href="anything.html">+anything</a></p>
...
```

jQuery:

```
$(".comment").each(function() {
    var comment = $(this).html();
    //check if any string in 'comment' starts with plus 
    //get new var for the plus string(s) 
    //if yes append and prepend necessary code for link 
    //change comment to comment with modified plus strings
    $(this).html(newcomment);
});
```

Comment: what happens when someone has to do some basic math in your comments :))

Comment: The plus just replaced something else I'm gonna use. So that shouldn't be a problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
str.replace(/\+(\w+)/g, '<a href="$1.html">$1</a>');
```

Check the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8gd3tyhf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cmt= $(".comment");
$(cmt).each(function() {
var comment = $(this);
var plus=comment.find("a").text();
var idexof=plus.indexOf("+");
if(idexof!=0)
{
    //do somthing
 comment.find("a").text("anytext");
 }
 else
 {
   //do somthing
 }


});
```

I hope it's Work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, and you can even use an inline function to perform the replacement.

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').html(function(i,txt) {
    return txt.replace(/\+(\w+)/g, function(match,word,ps,str) {
      return '<a href="' + word + '.html">' + match + '</a>';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="comment">A comment with +anything</p>
<p class="comment">A comment with +anything</p>
```